# Efficient way of finding potential substitutes in python string

Tags: python, string-matching

Say I have a "ground truth" string such as `ABA1234`, and I have a "predicted" string that I want to compare it to, for example `_ABA1234`, and I have a list of acceptable substitutions for example

```py
{
 "A": ["_A", "A"],
 "1": ["I", "1"],
}
```

What is the most efficient way of deciding whether or not the predicted string is equal to the target "ground truth" string with the given acceptable substitutions?

The brute force method - of generating candidates from the ground truth string by applying the substitutions is exponential, and not suitable for my purposes. Does anyone know a sub-exponential runtime algo for this kind of problem? Can `regex` help here?

Comment: Is your map of acceptable substitutions always going to have single character keys?

Comment: Well, 1 -> 1 is not really a useful substitution at all, and neither is A -> A, so really the only rules you have are A -> _A and 1 -> I, so from ABA1234 and these two rules you can only generate a grand total of 8 strings.

Comment: One usual trick to make it more efficient though, is to compute the inverse rules, and use them go backwards from _ABA1234. Go both forwards from ABA1234 and backwards from _ABA1234. Stop as soon as you find a string which is reachable forwards from ABA1234 and backwards from _ABA1234. Instead of exploring one tree, you'll have explored two trees of half-height, which is a huge gain since the size of a tree is exponential in its height.

Comment: @Holloway yes, the keys will always be single character keys. while bidirectional bfs is naturally a solution, I'm trying to avoid doing any kind of tree exploration. pierre-d is there a trivial non-tree solution?

Comment: With the substitutions given as example, I don't think there is much ambiguity: for example, when the regex encounters `'_A'`, at that point in the pattern the corresponding possibilities are `(?:A|_A)`, which is immediately decidable (no backtracking). When a `'I'` is encountered, then the matcher would have `(?:I|1)`, also decidable without backtracking. At the first non-match, the whole matching is abandoned and the result is None. Are your rules considerably more complex? Can you give a teaser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in comments, with the specific substitutions given by the OP as example, there isn't much ambiguity. Consider a regex pattern based on the given `truth` and `substitutions`:

```py
>>> make_pattern('ABA1234', {'A': ['_A', 'A'], '1': ['I', '1']})
re.compile(r'(?:_A|A)B(?:_A|A)(?:I|1)234', re.UNICODE)
```

When the regex encounters `'_A'` in the test string, at that point in the pattern the corresponding possibilities are `(?:_A|A)`, which is immediately decidable (no backtracking). When a `'I'` is encountered, then the pattern would have `(?:I|1)`, also decidable without backtracking. At the first non-match, the whole pattern is abandoned and the result is `None`.

As @KellyBundy shows, it is easy to construct simple examples that will lead to much higher backtracking complexity. For example:

```py
{
    'A': ['A', 'AB'],
    'B': ['BC', 'C'],
}
```

This answer assumes that the "exponential complexity" the OP mentions refers to the size of the tree of possible candidates (all the strings that could match the truth given the substitutions; in the OP's example, that size is 8 (`2**3`) because there are 3 parts with two alternates each). But we don't have to explore that tree at all, as indicated above.

If the complexity comes from ambiguous substitutions instead (as per Kelly's examples), then this answer won't help.

With these caveats, as the question currently stands and per OP's confirmation, simply compiling a regex pattern gives excellent performance:

**Edit**: at OP's request, we now allow arbitrary prefix and suffix to be present in the test string.

```py
import re

def make_pattern(truth, substitutions):
    pat = ''.join([
        f"(?:{'|'.join([re.escape(s) for s in substitutions.get(c)])})"
        if c in substitutions else re.escape(c)
        for c in truth
    ])
    return re.compile(f'{pat}')
```

Then:

```py
substitutions = {'A': ['_A', 'A'], '1': ['I', '1']}
truth = 'ABA1234'

pat = make_pattern(truth, substitutions)
test = 'xxxx_ABA1234xxxxx'

>>> bool(pat.search(test))
True

%timeit bool(pat.search(test))
330 ns ± 0.0872 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

Let's generate arbitrarily longer random input:

```py
import random

def gen(n, noise=.2):
    base = list(substitutions.items()) + [
        s for v in substitutions.values() for s in v
    ] + list('BCD02345_')
    parts = random.choices(base, k=n)  # may contain single elems and tuples
    truth = ''.join([s[0] if isinstance(s, tuple) else s for s in parts])
    test = ''.join([
        random.choice(s[1]) if isinstance(s, tuple) else s for s in parts
    ])
    # add noise prefix and suffix
    a = [s[0] if isinstance(s, tuple) else s for s in base]
    prefix = ''.join(random.choices(a, k=round(n * noise)))
    suffix = ''.join(random.choices(a, k=round(n * noise)))
    test = f'{prefix}{test}{suffix}'
    return truth, test
```

Examples:

```py
random.seed(0)  # for reproducibility
n = 50
truth, test = gen(n)

>>> truth
'43BACB3ICD5CI30A5_45I252C1B05_C4A4DA2142AC5AI5_ADA_'

>>> test
'_5_CII1I5A43BACB3ICD5CI30A5_45I252C1B05_C4A4D_A2142_AC5AI5_ADA_3DI13IA_A4A'

pat = make_pattern(truth, substitutions)
>>> bool(pat.search(test))
True

%timeit bool(pat.search(test))
527 ns ± 0.174 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

With `n = 10_000` (so both `truth` and `test` will be no smaller than that):

```py
random.seed(0)  # for reproducibility
n = 10_000
truth, test = gen(n)

>>> len(truth), len(test)
(10645, 15238)

pat = make_pattern(truth, substitutions)
>>> bool(pat.search(test))
True

%timeit bool(pat.search(test))
129 µs ± 21.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

(Meanwhile, building the pattern itself is very predictable --no backtracking-- and takes ~4ms for 10K-char string).

Comment: [3 seconds](https://tio.run/##hZDBSsQwEIbveYqhCE209KAIUlhkW99iqdKNUxttk5BMD7L22WuSosviwRwy4c8/3wy//aTB6LsH69ZVTdY4AoeMvWIPU/eBL7YjQqc5uZmGAvx89KRoJmW0FxWDcIIFdpDn5btRmh@SFk@f8cfqlH/9fDgs0cvOIvcCeuPAg9KXxPINiUvRikVkvxzVg/zjBBw9gjwPC7zkSosmuRWpOKTZ6VBKaSarRuR9/nwKSy9XuWDskrqDU2rK9lkFh3AX4VlnbbGpdVLrJspNVBfG0sAYwL7O4Rpu7@EmhMHYFsv/ITJCT1t/cwY8RYJTmvjRmJEHQjl1JAce3UKIdf0G) for strings shorter than 100 chars.

Comment: ...yes, of course, with considerably more complexity -- that's what I was asking in comments. But I'd rather like for the OP to spell out where the complexity stems from (no pun) than guessing.

Comment: Well, they do talk about exponential runtime, so I guess that's indeed something they have in mind. Anyway, [simpler/smaller case](https://tio.run/##hZDPSsQwEMbv8xRDEZJI6cE/uBQW6XMsVbpxaqNtEpLpQWqfvWYjriwenENmmHzfLzPxHzw4e7vzYdvM5F1gDATwQj1O3Ts9@46ZgpUcZh5KjPMxsuGZjbNR1YApkgT3KET15oyVh9w7RV/Ix3oRnz8XgSqKuvMko8LeBYxo7CWxeiWWWrVqVcWZY3rUf5RIYyTUv48lXlblQXO7VTkF4jnYlCrtJm9Gkr14WtLQ65VQAJfUPS7ZVDRFjYd0lqlsiraEFSCjT6s2Aq/x5gHge/X/PwqYIp@d93fJGYxleXRulMlZTR3rQZ5USqlt@wI) taking 10 seconds.

Comment: Well, they are also talking about _generating_ candidates. Even with the OP-provided example, a naive solution would _generate_ an exponential (8 = 2^3) number of candidates. So before plunging into much more complicated approaches, I'd like to check what the actual complexity is. I stand by my current answer until the question changes and gives harder examples. Your guesses are good ones, but let's wait and see what the OP really wants.

Comment: hey thanks for this! I did not consider brute forcing regex. How about the following case now - in the `predicted_text`, I can now have arbitrary characters such as `RANDOM_CHARS_ABA1234`, then how would the regex change?

Comment: How about `substitutions.get(c, c)` instead of `substitutions.get(c)`? Then you don't need the ternary, and special chars in truth get escaped as well.

Comment: my `predicted_text` string would be less than 50 chars, and this regex solution seems to work

Comment: ah I'll just switch `return re.compile(f'^{pat}$')` to `return re.compile(f'^.*{pat}.*$')`

Comment: @KellyBundy the ternary came in because I wanted to avoid single terms groups such as `(?:A)`. Agreed to escape single terms `c` as well (edited).

Comment: yes, the modified truth will be surrounded by arbitrary strings